# Play sound on mobile web with 3g connection

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I have a website which have a few sound files to be played.

**What happens:**

- If I open the site from my phone with a Wifi connection, it works fine.
- If I open the site from my computer with the 3g connection provided with my
  phone it works too, so it's not a problem with connection.

**What I know:**

I've tried my site with Dolphin, Firefox and Opera and it is not working.

I've tried and I can hear music from grooveshark and see videos from youtube on those mobile browsers.

**Then:**

Is there any way to get over this restriction?

**Edit:**

```
<div class="div1">
    <img id="segundoFondo" src="../images/audio_fondo1.png" style="width:100%;border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;" />
        <div class="div2"> 
            <a class="playback" href="#">
                <img id="play" src="../images/audio_botplay_a.png" />
            </a>

            <a class="stopback" href="#">
                <img id="stop" src="../images/audio_botstop_a.png" />
            </a>

        </div>

        <audio id="calle13">
            <source src="../audio/calle13.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to actually show us your code, and explain what codecs you have in use.

Comment: Hello Brad, thanks for your comment, there I add the code I am using. It is very simple..

Comment: I am using some Jquery to start it and stop it, but I think it doesn't  have nothing to do with the connection..